# Crystal Report PrintToPrinter Timeout Error

Tags: crystal-reports, timeout

In VS 2008, I have a crystal main report with about 20 sub reports. These sub reports all run their own individual query. When viewing the report in CrystalReportViewer, I can see the entire report without any hassles. The same thing happens at the client's PC.

The problem comes in at the client when using the PrintToPrinter function. I get a "The server request timed out" error. When using it on my side, it works 100% but not at the client.

To resolve this, I tried increasing the Crystal timeout to 180 seconds via the following command:

**oReport.Subreports["TicketBoxCorro.rpt"].DataSourceConnections[0].Attributes.Collection.Set("Command Timeout", "180");
oReport.Subreports["TicketBoxCorro.rpt"].DataSourceConnections[0].SetConnection(this.DBServer, this.DBDatabase, this.DBUsername, this.DBPassword);**

The problem is that on the clients machine, the error pops up just after a minute, it never reaches 180 seconds.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not to worry, I finally solved this. Perhaps I should have mentioned that my report is printed from an UpdatePanel. Now the error message pops up because the UpdatePanel was timing out - for those who don't know, the default timeout is 90 seconds which I just discovered. You can override this in the script manager.

This probably explains why I had no answers =)